# Xamarin Android bottom navigation not displaying on all screens

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android, bottomnavigationview

I have implemented bottom navigation in Xamarin Android. I need to show different screens when clicking each icon in bottom navigation bar. 
I is working fine in main activity but on Selection on bottom navigation item, how to show new screen while keeping bottom navigation visible.
When clicking icon in bottom navigation bar I setContent again so bottom navigation bar hides(as new content is loaded that does not have bottom navigation bar).

I have very little experience in Xamarin Android so don't know if there is anything like layout page which can hold bottom navigation.

[image]

[image]

I read about **Framelayout and fragments** but don't know how to implement with bottom navigation. Any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: Your question is a little bit vague and tough to answer, with little detail but from what I do understand I will add an answer soon. Correct me if I am wrong though you want on tab item click that it should show different pages right?

Comment: bottom navigation bar disappear when I click any menu - reason being I set Content again on menu click. Shall I need to define bottom navigation bar on every page ?

Comment: No I am updating an answer you can check it out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are changing the ContentView of your Activity it is disappearing:

You can follow the below steps to achieve a BottomNavigationView:

- Since we are dealing with Fragments, I will change my MainActivity base class to `Android.Support.V7.App.AppCompatActivity`, and yes we will be using Android Support library V4.Since I am dealing with Fragments, I will change my MainActivity base class to `Android.Support.V7.App.AppCompatActivity`, and yes we will be using Android Support library V4 and V7. Check this blog for [understanding support libraries](https://blog.xamarin.com/mastering-android-support-libraries/)

  ```
  public class MainActivity : Android.Support.V7.App.AppCompatActivity
  ```
- Create a layout for our MainActivity, We will add a FrameLayout to hold our Fragment, a ViewPager, and a BottomNavigationView from the Android.Support.Design library, Something like below:

  ```
   <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
  <FrameLayout
   android:id="@+id/fragment_content"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
   android:layout_above="@+id/bottom_navigation" />
  <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
   android:id="@+id/viewpager"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
   android:layout_above="@id/bottom_navigation" />
  <android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
   android:id="@+id/bottom_navigation"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="56dp"
   android:layout_gravity="start"
   android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
   android:background="@android:color/white"
   app:menu="@menu/navigation_main" />
  </RelativeLayout>
  ```
- Create a layout for Fragment as well. I will keep it simple with an icon and a label, you can keep whatever you desire here:

  ```
  <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent">
   <ImageView
   android:id="@+id/imageView"
   android:src="@drawable/abc_ic_star_black_48dp"
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:layout_centerInParent="true" />
   <TextView
   android:id="@+id/title"
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:layout_centerInParent="true"
   android:text="Fragment"
   android:textAlignment="center"
   android:textSize="@dimen/abc_text_size_display_1_material"
   android:layout_below="@id/imageView"
   android:layout_centerVertical="false" />
   </RelativeLayout>
  ```
- Let’s get to that bottom navigation. First, we need the navigation items (tabs) for the BottomNavigationView, we will add a navigation menu for this.

  **navigation_main.xml** //Name of xml file

  ```
   <menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

   <item
     android:orderInCategory="0"
     android:id="@+id/menu_genres"
     android:enabled="true"
     android:title="Genres"
     android:icon="@drawable/tab_genres"
     app:showAsAction="always" />

    <item
      android:orderInCategory="1"
      android:id="@+id/menu_titles"
      android:enabled="true"
      android:title="Titles"
      android:icon="@drawable/tab_titles"
      app:showAsAction="always" />

     <item
      android:orderInCategory="2"
      android:id="@+id/menu_stream"
      android:enabled="true"
      android:title="Stream"
      android:icon="@drawable/tab_stream"
      app:showAsAction="always" />

   <item
      android:orderInCategory="3"
      android:id="@+id/menu_showtimes"
      android:enabled="true"
      android:title="Showtimes"
      android:icon="@drawable/tab_showtimes"
      app:showAsAction="always" />
    </menu>
  ```

  Notice the `orderInCategory`, this is the order of tab items from left to right.

  Alright, Now We have put together the views we will be working with. Now let’s get to that BottomNavigationView.

  In MainActivity get hold of the BottomNavigationView and set it up.

  ```
    bottomNavigationView= FindViewById<BottomNavigationView>(Resource.Id.bottom_navigation);
  ```
- Also, the BottomNavigationView hides the labels if the tabs grow more than 3. So, let’s change that. Add this helper method to your code and call it when setting up the BottomNavigationView like this,

  ```
  RemoveShiftMode(_navigationView);//Below the FindViewById

  private void RemoveShiftMode(BottomNavigationView view)  // a Method in the Activity
  {   
  var menuView = (BottomNavigationMenuView) view.GetChildAt(0);
  try
  {
    var shiftingMode = menuView.Class.GetDeclaredField("mShiftingMode");
    shiftingMode.Accessible = true;
    shiftingMode.SetBoolean(menuView, false);
    shiftingMode.Accessible = false;

    for (int i = 0; i < menuView.ChildCount; i++)
    {
     var item = (BottomNavigationItemView)menuView.GetChildAt(i);
     item.SetShiftingMode(false);
     // set checked value, so view will be updated
     item.SetChecked(item.ItemData.IsChecked);
    }
    } catch (System.Exception ex) {
   System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine((ex.InnerException??ex).Message);
   }
  }
  ```

  And now, we should be okay. And that’s it. we are done with setting up the BottomNavigationView. We have not implemented the fragments for each tab yet, so tapping on the tabs won’t present anything. We will present the fragments inside the ViewPager.
- Now, let’s set up the ViewPager. First, the adapter,

  ```
  public class ViewPagerAdapter : FragmentPagerAdapter
  {
     Fragment[] _fragments;

    public ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm, Fragment[] fragments) : base(fm)
    {
      _fragments = fragments;
    }

    public override int Count => _fragments.Length;

    public override Fragment GetItem(int position) => _fragments[position];
  }
  ```
- Then, the ViewPager,

  ```
  // find the view
  _viewPager = FindViewById<ViewPager>(Resource.Id.viewpager);

  // set the adapter
  _viewPager.Adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(SupportFragmentManager, _fragments);
  ```

  and that should be it for setting up the ViewPager.
- When the user slides between ViewPager views, ViewPager.PageSelected event is fired. Similarly, when the user taps on a tab (navigation menu item) in the BottomNavigationView, the BottomNavigationView.NavigationItemSelected event is fired. We have to link these two events to make the BottomNavigationView and ViewPager dance in sync. Here’s how we’re going to do it.

  Declare an event handler for  BottomNavigationView and ViewPager as follows,

  ```
   // wireup the page selection event
   _viewPager.PageSelected += ViewPager_PageSelected; 

  // wire up the selection event 
   _navigationView.NavigationItemSelected += NavigationView_NavigationItemSelected;
  ```
- When the ViewPager page is selected, we notify the BottomNavigationView and vice versa. Like this,

  ```
     private void ViewPager_PageSelected(object sender, ViewPager.PageSelectedEventArgs e)
      {
       var item = _navigationView.Menu.GetItem(e.Position);
       _navigationView.SelectedItemId = item.ItemId;
      }

      void NavigationView_NavigationItemSelected(object sender, 
      BottomNavigationView.NavigationItemSelectedEventArgs e)
      {
        _viewPager.SetCurrentItem(e.Item.Order, true);
      }
  ```
- And that’s it. Now the BottomNavigationView and ViewPager are displaying the selected fragment/page/tab and updating each other with a smooth transition.

One last thing, load fragments for these tabs.

```
      void InitializeTabs()
 {
     _fragments = new Fragment[] {
     TheFragment.NewInstance("Genres", "tab_genres"),
     TheFragment.NewInstance("Titles", "tab_titles"),
     TheFragment.NewInstance("Stream", "tab_stream"),
     TheFragment.NewInstance("Showtimes", "tab_showtimes")
     };
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

The bottom bar is added to the first activity . If you change the activity, on selection the bottom bar would disappear.

You need to add view pager with fragment to achieve it

You can check out this [tutorial](https://intelliabb.com/2017/12/02/tutorial-bottomnavigationview-and-viewpager-in-xamarin-android/)

You can also see this code [sample](https://github.com/pooja-kamath/ViewPagerWithinFragment)

Comment: Thanks, these tutorial are helpful :)